# Questions about Visual Studio Express and Professional

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

If I have a project that I created in Visual Studio Professional (say, 2013) that uses the database functionality, would I still be able to open the project and make edits to the code using Express? Why I ask this is because we are a small software development firm. The budget limit we have means we'd like to keep purchases to the minimum. The main features we need for Visual Studio Professional is mainly creating the executable (.msi or .exe) and the database features.

If we simply buy one copy of VS Professional, could other developers work with the Express edition for development, and only use the Professional edition when we need to work on functionality that is outside of Express' features such as database and creating executables?

My last question is - based on Visual Studio Professional's licensing scheme, only one person logged in at a time can use it, is that correct?

I apologize if this is the incorrect place to ask this. Let me know and I will delete it.

Comment: @PriyankThakkar Not quite true: "Visual Studio Express products are available at no charge **and may be used for commercial, production usage** subject to the license terms provided with each product." [link](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs)

Comment: As far I know, what features there you can compare over website. But express edition is only meant for students. I am editing my comments. http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/support/faq-vs link suggest it can be used for commercial purpose.

Comment: @crashmstr: I was making the same edit. But this site cant allow to edit the comment before 5 mins of its posted time :( :(

Answer (score 0):

As Visual Studio 2012 Express is free, there's nothing to stop you from downloading it and seeing whether it suits your needs.

As far as I can recall, Express edition does come with a database explorer, so you should be able to do basic SQL Server tasks using it. But as I pointed out, you should be able to try VS 2012 Express edition without any obligations.

Also, be aware that there is a SQL Server Management Studio Express edition available ([2012 edition for example](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)) from Microsoft. I believe this is also free, and should be more then adequate to interacting with SQL Server if using VS 2012 Express edition doesn't work out for you.

Comment: Hi Jason. Thanks for the reply. Would there be any compatibility issues with opening projects/solutions that were created with Professional in Express? Also, are you aware of how the licensing works - that is, say we buy one license, is that license only accessible for one developer at a time, but can be installed on many machines?

Comment: Not familiar with licensing I'm afraid, but I would say that it's one licence per developer, but that would be worth checking with Microsoft themselves. I doubt that a project created in Pro edition will not open in Express, unless you have used a Pro specific feature.